# Find all paths from start to end node using BFS

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, breadth-first-search

Using the below implementation of BFS, how can we modify the program to store all paths from start to end node? Any ideas?

```
def bfs(graph_to_search, start, end):
    queue = [[start]]
    visited = set()

    while queue:
        # Gets the first path in the queue
        path = queue.pop(0)

        # Gets the last node in the path
        vertex = path[-1]

        # Checks if we got to the end
        if vertex == end:
            return path
        # We check if the current node is already in the visited nodes set in order not to recheck it
        elif vertex not in visited:
            # enumerate all adjacent nodes, construct a new path and push it into the queue
            for current_neighbour in graph_to_search.get(vertex, []):
                new_path = list(path)
                new_path.append(current_neighbour)
                queue.append(new_path)

            # Mark the vertex as visited
            visited.add(vertex)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this could work. I think when checking if a node is in visited you will exclude many paths from the results, simply because they contain the same node. I changed it to add the entire path to visited, and check this instead. As well created a empty list `results` which we append to if final node is found. Your code will return from the function the minute the last node is found, and wont explore and find the remaining paths. Let me know if this works!

```
def bfs(graph_to_search, start, end):
    queue = [[start]]
    visited = set()
    results = []

    while queue:
        # Gets the first path in the queue
        path = queue.pop(0)

        # Gets the last node in the path
        vertex = path[-1]

        # Checks if we got to the end
        if vertex == end:
            results.append(path)
            continue
        # We check if the current path is already in the visited nodes set in order not to recheck it
        elif path not in visited:
            # enumerate all adjacent nodes, construct a new path and push it into the queue
            for current_neighbour in graph_to_search.get(vertex, []):
                new_path = path.copy()
                new_path.append(current_neighbour)
                queue.append(new_path)

            # Mark the vertex as visited
            visited.add(path)
      return results
```

you could also save the elements in the `queue` as tuples containing current vertex and the previous path like this. Might be a little bit more readable.

```
queue = [(start, [])]
vertex, path = queue.pop(0)
```

Comment: A bit late to the party (I came here through a google search), but can I ask why the visited set is needed at all? It seems that the condition `path not in visited` will always be true, since all paths added to the queue are unique (i.e. the same path is never added twice).